# ncurses program not working correctly when used for command substitution

Tags: c++, bash, command-line-arguments, ncurses

I would like to be able to call an ncurses based program via command substitution so its output can be passed as a command line argument to the another program. For example, this is easy to do in bash when the program does not go into curses mode:

```
echo $(pwd) # should be the same as just calling pwd alone
```

When I try to do this with my program (whose code follows below), curses mode is never entered, and the string "test" is never printed. It is important to enter curses mode because this is where, theoretically, the user would somehow manipulate the string that is finally printed to stdout (right now that string is just static).

```
echo $(./a.out) # just prints an empty line
```

My program will return the string "this is not a test" when run normally after curses mode is entered, "test" is printed to the screen, and the user presses a key.

```
./a.out # normal run
```

Here is the offending code:

```
// test.cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* get curses up and running */
void init() {
    initscr(); // start curses mode, might clear screen
    raw(); // disable line buff, and C-z/C-c won't gen sigals; see cbreak()
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE); // enable arrow keys and function keys
    noecho(); // don't echo chars user types
}

/* shut curses down */
void end() {
   endwin(); // end curses mode
}

int main()
{
    init();
    printw("test");
    getch();
    end();

    cout << "this is not a test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with this command:

```
g++ test.cpp -lcurses
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably because the program runs in an environment where the "console" is not directly available as a device. For example, the shell is probably opening the output as a pipe.

Comment: Is there anyway around that?

Comment: Perhaps try something like `if (isatty(fileno(stdin)) ... else ...` or some such to determine if the input is something that has "tty" capabilities (that is, it's not a file or pipe, essentially) - where the two sections of `...` indicates initinialize curses or not initializing curses.

Comment: I always want to initialize curses though. Is there anyway to force the shell to treat it like a normal program? I was looking around and saw something about how the command in `$()` will be run in a sub shell by bash if that helps.

Comment: Right, I'm only guessing that is the reason. You could try something like "cat file.txt | ./a.out" or "a.out | more" and see which, it not both, have the same effect. If so, no there's nothing you can do, since you need a "true" TTY to be able to use ncurses, a non-TTY device won't support the operations curses will want (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: @MatthewMellott: I modified your code and tested it this time; result is in a new answer. My error; I meant /dev/tty but typed /dev/console. I should have tested. Also, it turns out that you need to use two different fds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution, using `newterm`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    // start curses mode
    SCREEN* s = NULL;
    FILE* out = stdout;
    if(!isatty(fileno(stdout))) {
        out = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");
        // Should really test `out` to make sure that worked.
        setbuf(out, NULL);
    }
    // Here, we don't worry about the case where stdin has been
    // redirected, but we could do something similar to out
    // for input, opening "/dev/tty" in mode "r" for in if necessary.
    s = newterm(NULL, out, stdin);

    printw("test");
    getch();

    endwin(); // end curses mode
    delscreen(s);
    puts("/home/matt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the fish shell? For some reason this works in bash and sh but not fish.

Comment: @MatthewMellott: I know virtually nothing about the fish shell. However, it is always useful to specify *how* things fail to work. "doesn't work" is impossibly broad to diagnose. The first thing I'd do is add failure tests throughout the code.

Comment: When trying `echo (./a.out)`, for example, curses mode is not entered a only a newline is printed.

Comment: @MatthewMellott: My guess -- and it is just a guess -- is that fish starts parenthesized commands in a way that prevents them from accessing the terminal. Did you insert a check to see if /dev/tty is being opened correctly for writing? for reading? Did you check the return code of ./a.out?

Comment: Opened /dev/tty for reading and writing and both file descriptors were not null. The return code is zero.

Comment: @MatthewMellott: perhaps the job is stopped? Did you try `jobs`?

Comment: That seems to be the problem! When `echo (./a.out)` is run, ./a.out is getting stopped.